# CreateNumeric Vector Method throwing an error using R.NET in IronPython

Tags: r, ironpython, r.net

I am using R.NET in IronPython in Visual Studio 2012.  The code below works fine:

```py
import clr
from System import *
from System.IO import *
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\\PythonDev\\MSP_Script\\Python\\MSP_Script\\RDotNet.dll")

from RDotNet import *

envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")

rBinPath = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.2\\bin\\i386"
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath)

engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet")
engine.Initialize()

group2 = engine.Evaluate("group2 <- c(29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98, 30.02, 29.98)")
```

But as soon as I add the following line of code:

`group1 = engine.CreateNumericVector((30.02, 29.99, 30.11, 29.97, 30.01, 29.99))`

I get the error "AttributeError: 'REngine' object has no attribute 'CreateNumericVector'"

If I run the same code in C# it works fine.  I have Googled this for some time now and cant find any pointers.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are trying to call is not an actual member of [REngine](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#R.NET/REngine.cs) but an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977.aspx) as seen in the [sources](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#R.NET/REngineExtension.cs).
If you add the following extension import it will work as expected:

```py
from RDotNet import REngineExtension
clr.ImportExtensions(REngineExtension)
```